# html nested table hide or show table row by clicking table row first td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am doing one project, in which I want to display data in nested table structure, like in [link](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/05/gridview-with-in-gridview-or-nested.html)

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/05/gridview-with-in-gridview-or-nested.html

In that please check in down demo. It was implemented in grid view in asp.net. But I am trying to implementing in html. I got solution but, problem is that in that table if I am clicking any where in the row it is displaying next row. but I need first td of tr is clicked then only I have to display the tr other wise nothing,
and my html code is below.
Please anybody help me.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $(".toptable > tbody > tr:not(.accordion)").hide();
  $(".toptable tr:first-child").show();
  $(".toptable tr.accordion").click(function(){
  $(this).next().fadeToggle();

    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table class="toptable" border="1">
                <tbody>                   
                    <tr class="accordion">
                        <td class="id1">TD1</td>
                        <td>TD2</td>
                        <td>TD3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <table class="nested" border="1" >
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>nestedTD1</td>
                                        <td>nestedTD2</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>nestedTD3</td>
                                        <td>nestedTD4</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>          
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr class="accordion">
                        <td>TD1</td>
                        <td>TD2</td>
                        <td>TD3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <table class="nested" border="1" >
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>nestedTD1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>nestedTD3</td>


                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `td:first` in your selector to select the first td and `parent().next()` to toggle the next `tr`

try this

```
 $(".toptable tr.accordion td:first").click(function(){
                       //--^^^^^^^^---here
     $(this).parent().next().fadeToggle();
      //----^^^^^^^^^---here
});
```

**updated**

after the comment below

> it is not not working for second row.means if iam clicking on second row first td it has to show some other table row.

try this

```
$(".toptable tr").find('td:first').click(function(){
     $(this).parent().next().fadeToggle();
});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/TtWTR/3/)

Comment: i need to display next tr but it fadeToggle(); effect is effecting to td

Comment: did u try the updated code... `$(this).parent().next().fadeToggle();` ?? this should work

Comment: it is working for first row only. it is not not working for second row.means if iam clicking on second row first td it has to show  some other table row http://jsfiddle.net/TtWTR/

Comment: in that link example is there please check

Comment: hay please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651358/html-nested-table-hide-or-show-table-last-td-by-clicking-table-row-first-td