# html nested table hide or show table last td by clicking table row first td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I want to display data in nested table structure (please check following link)

See my code below. It was implemented in grid view in asp.net, but I am trying to implementing in html.

The problem is:

- if I am clicking in the first table cell (td)  the last td should be shown.
- currently it does not display the last td
- initially last td should be hidden.

Please help me.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $(".toptable > tbody > tr > td:not(.n1)").hide();
            $(".toptable tr").find('td:first').click(function() {
                $(this).find('td:last').show();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="toptable" border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="accordion">
                <td class="id1 n1">TD1</td>
                <td class="id1 n1">TD2</td>
                <td class="id1 n1">TD3</td>
                <td class="nested">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <table border="1">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>nestedTD1</td>
                                        <td>nestedTD2</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>nestedTD3</td>
                                        <td>nestedTD4</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="accordion">
                <td class="id1 n1">TD1</td>
                <td class="id1 n1">TD2</td>
                <td class="id1 n1">TD3</td>
                <td class="nested">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <table border="1">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>nestedTD1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>nestedTD3</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: can u give an example .. which last td are you talkiong about

Comment: in every tr last td i have to toggle show of every tr first td click. initially last td is hidden. for that please remove script tag u can understand or please check this link http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/05/gridview-with-in-gridview-or-nested.html

Comment: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/05/gridview-with-in-gridview-or-nested.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
 $(function () {
     $(".toptable > tbody > tr > td:not(.n1)").hide();
     $(".toptable tr").find("td:first").click(function () {         
         $(this).closest('tr').children('td:last').show();
     });
 });
```

Also check sample on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7Jfx7/1/

Comment: ok vijay. i want to show last td ad new row. that means it should look like new row

Comment: i need out put like that closest('tr'). should be in inside td because i will apply sorting also. for that i cannot apply this logic

Comment: You can not place `tr` inside `td` there has to be `table>tr>td` sequence to show data in it.

Comment: ok. what i posted above code please execute by removing. script tag and check output

Answer (score 0):

ok i think i got what are you sayin .. use siblings() instead of `find()`

try this

```
  $(function() {
        $(".toptable > tbody > tr > td:not(.n1)").hide();
        $(".toptable tr").find('td:first').click(function() {
            $(this).siblings('.nested').show(); // or  $(this).siblings().last().show(); 
        });
    });
```

and you cannot have `<tr>` inside `<td>` that is invalid.. change that

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/fPEnV/)

Comment: $(function () {
     $(".toptable > tbody > tr > td:not(.n1)").hide();
     $(".toptable tr").find("td:first").click(function () {         
         $(this).closest('tr').children('td:last').fadeToggle();
     });
 });

Comment: ok.but try above i.e. whatever i posted. remove script tag and execte. i need like that output

Comment: because i need to apply sorting also

Answer (score 0):

### Update Answer

Check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/CaP23/1/

If you want to show the hidden row as a new row, you need to modify your html like this.

### HTML

```
<table class="toptable" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="accordion">
            <td class="showHide">+</td>
            <td class="id1 n1">TD1</td>
            <td class="id1 n1">TD2</td>
            <td class="id1 n1">TD3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="nested">
            <td colspan="4">
                <table border="1">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>nestedTD1</td>
                            <td>nestedTD2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>nestedTD3</td>
                            <td>nestedTD4</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".toptable tr.nested").hide();
    $(".toptable td.showHide").on('click',function () {
        if($(this).html() == '+'){
            $(this).html('-');
            $(this).parent('tr').next('tr.nested').show();
        }
        else{
            $(this).html('+');
            $(this).parent('tr').next('tr.nested').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i need show that data in next row for that i wrote like that. please check this link http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/05/gridview-with-in-gridview-or-nested.html inthat link go down some demo there. i need lie that

Answer (score 0):

First of all your html is not proper
please remove `<tr><td colspan="3"> and </td></tr>`
http://jsfiddle.net/code_rum/aBWFY/

Instead of finding your td using class you can use last:child

```
$(function () {

    $(".toptable > tbody > tr > td:not(.n1)").hide();
    $(".toptable tr").find('td:first').click(function () {
  $(this).siblings(':last-child').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: please check this link http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/05/gridview-with-in-gridview-or-nested.html

Comment: in that link demo is there i need otpt like that

Answer (score 0):

I made a  **[fully working demo of a master detail table](http://plnkr.co/edit/2Du5v7dvl4a7BWWI2FDH?p=preview)** because that is what i understood. Since i hope it may be of use i post it here anyways.

The code is really simple. The class `hiddenRow` is defined as: `.hiddenRow {display: none;}`. if the
user clicks on the button this class is removed.

```
<tr class="accordion">
      <td class="id1 n1">
        <button onClick="showDetail('#m1-detail');">show detail</button>
      </td>
      <td class="id1 n1">master row 1</td>
      <td class="id1 n1">some </td>
      <td class="nested">information</td>
</tr>
<tr id="m1-detail" class="hiddenRow">
   ....
</tr>
```

The function uses jquery and look like this

```
function showDetail(selector)
{
  // if the class is already there remove it else add it         
  if($(selector).hasClass("hiddenRow")){
    $(selector).removeClass("hiddenRow");
  }else {
    $(selector).addClass("hiddenRow");
  }      
};
```

#### Update - details are shown in last cell (td) of table row

I forked my demo above to this **[working demo where details are displayed in last cell](http://plnkr.co/edit/qlR92Dq1qTUYmePt1rxX?p=preview)**

[image: updated master detail - detail shown in last column]